# JMeter HTTP POST based on HTTP GET

Tags: java, http, testing, jmeter

I am using JMeter to do some testing.
I have  to do a HTTP GET on a URL like `www.acme.com/documents/next`.

This shall return me a document ID, then i need to do a POST based on that document ID like
`www.acme.com/document/{document_id}`. This document ID shall be the one returned by the previous GET request.

I will need to run this in many threads, so if there needs to be a variable used to store the result of the GET, it should be stored in something like a ThreadLocal because each one will get a unique id when it called the GET method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use postprocessor to extract variable. Your test plan will look like this:

```
Thread Group
- GET request to /documents/next
--- Regular Expression Extractor (with reference name=variable)
- POST request to /document/${variable}
```